# Launch another iOS application upon a button click from my iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, intune

I want the user to launch "[Microsoft Intune Company portal](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/intune-company-portal/id719171358?mt=8)" iOS application when the user clicks "update" button from my application.
Is there a way I can do this?

Nothing much, just want the users to launch and land in InTune app.

If this is not possible, suggest how can I work around this. Solution architech of my project rejected the idea of hosting .ipa from server location. He wants the app to be hosted in InTune

Comment: Extract that app and check it's info.plist - if it has a supported URLScheme you can launch it via that.  If it doesn't then you can't

Answer (score 0):

URL Scheme is the proper method to open another app.

[Click here for Tutorial On URL Scheme](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes--mobile-6629)